# What does "the tassels on the latter bristling" mean?

Tags: meaning

> The same face: the very same. Marley in his pigtail, usual waistcoat, tights and boots; the tassels on the latter bristling, like his pigtail, and his coat-skirts, and the hair upon his head.

I can't get the 'the tassels on the latter bristling' part. Please try to help me to get this.

Comment: Did Mick's answer clarify, or are you confused about what "on the latter" means?

Comment: Oh, I understood every part of it. Thank you guys!!! : )

Comment: @joiedevivre Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leather boots sometimes have ***tassels***, mostly for decoration:

> **tassel** noun [ C ]
>   ​
>   a group of short threads or ropes held together at one end, used as a hanging decoration on hats, curtains, furniture, etc.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tassel)

[image]

The ***latter*** just means the second of two items (in this case, Marley's boots). Also, the *former* refers to the first of two items (and would indicate Marley's tights).

> **latter** noun [ S ]
>
> the latter
>   ​
>   the second of two people, things, or groups previously mentioned:
>
> - She offered me more money or a car and I chose the latter.
>
> Compare with: **former** noun

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/latter)

To ***bristle*** just means to stand up (or stick out):

> **bristle** verb [ I ] (of hair)
>
> to stand up:
>
> - The cat's fur bristled and it arched its back.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bristle)

So, the tassels on Marley's boots were standing up (like his pigtail, coat tails, and hair).